# Regex for string with double quotes and environment variable

Tags: regex, sed

Using sed, I need to replace a string that contains double quotes with an environment variable:

```
BUCKET_FOLDER=\"dev\"
```

(or any derivative of 'dev') needs to convert to:

```
BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1/$ID
```

where $ID = abcde, ie

```
BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1/abcde
```

To expand the $ID environment variable, I need to put double quotes around the sed substitution expression:

```
sed -e "s/BUCKET_FOLDER=\\"(.*?)\\"/BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1\/$ID/g" $string
```

but this is then preventing a match on the double quotes in the source string.

Would appreciate any advice. I can make it work with 2 steps, but would prefer 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
ID=abcde

echo 'A=\"x\" BUCKET_FOLDER=\"dev\" B=\"y\"' |sed -r "s|(.*)(BUCKET_FOLDER=)([^ ]+)(.*)|\1\2bucket1/$ID\4|g"
```

A=\"x\" BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1/abcde B=\"y\"

Using `|` as seprator in `sed`. As you mentioned, used double quotes to expand `$ID` and captured `BUCKET_FOLDER=` as first group.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty close. The only issue I have is that BUCKET_FOLDER=\"dev\" is part of a longer string, so you regex (by virtue  of the * glob) is replacing everything to the end of the longer string. The actual source string is more like 'A=\"x\" BUCKET_FOLDER=\"dev\" B=\"y\"'

Comment: Close again. Output is now BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1/abcde\"dev\"

Comment: @GarrethMcDaid tried fixing it more, if this doesn't work let me know i'll delete my post.

Comment: Had to tweak slightly for user case, but that seems to have got it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you escaped the quote correctly in the `sed` command. On the other hand, the way you specified the rest of the regex isn't how it's supposed to be. Here is my take on the story:

```
echo BUCKET_FOLDER='"'dev'"' | \
sed -e "s/BUCKET_FOLDER=\"\(.*\?\)\"/BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1\/$ID/g"
```

Explanation:

- I made the assumption that the `\"` parts in your `$string` variable are just escape sequences. Thus I used the `echo BUCKET_FOLDER='"'dev'"'` command. It's output is `BUCKET_FOLDER="dev"`.
- The non-greedy qualifier looks like this: `.*\?`. I.e. you need to escape the question mark.
- You need to escape the parentheses too: `\(...\)`. This should work without the group too, because you don't use backreferences like `\1`.

Alternatives:

If you want to eliminate the capturing group, then the sed expression becomes this:

```
sed -e "s/BUCKET_FOLDER=\".*\?\"/BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1\/$ID/g"
```

If the backslash is really part of your string, you can match them with the character class `[\]` :

```
echo BUCKET_FOLDER=\\'"'dev\\'"' | \
sed -e "s/BUCKET_FOLDER=[\]\".*\?[\]\"/BUCKET_FOLDER=bucket1\/$ID/g
```

Comment: Backslashes are part of the string. Its from an /etc/sysconfig/tomcat7 config file that sends extra parameters to JVM.